# GWT Post build command in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gwt, post-build-event

I am starting getting used to Eclipse, but I have much more experience with Visual Studio. In Visual Studio it is possible to run auto commands after the build has finished.

Now I am creating a GWT project and several other projects at once in one solution (or workspace) in Eclipse. Some files which are compiled with the GWT project needs to be copied to another location when they have been compiled. I am currently doing this manually and would like to do it automatically. I am not doing it often, since the project works fine in debug mode (...?gwt.codesvr=localhost:9997).

But where is the location for executing a post build command for a GWT project in eclipse? Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

Just open project properties, choose 'Builders' item and click on 'New...' button.

Comment: I am not quite sure how that can start a batch or commands after I click the GWT Suitcase (GWT Compile Project) and the compilation has finished. I am not that familiar with eclipse yet. Can you be a bit more specific on what I have to setup on these pages after clicking New...?

Answer (score 2):

Good question! I'm using Eclipse since about 2003, and I remember that I also wanted a functionality like that back then. However, I got so used to using ant for any serious build, that I completely forgot about it.

There is some useful ant integration in Eclipse (e.g. the ant view), and if you create your GWT project with [webAppCreator](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/create.html#create) you already get a few good ant targets you can build upon.

It would still be nice sometimes to have something more GUI-like to do simple multi-step builds with Eclipse. I haven't found anything like that yet, but it's absolutely possible that it exists, especially as a plugin.

Comment: I created a bat file doing all the copying stuff. It's not that automatic that I hoped for, but I just have to remember runing it each time I click the GWT Suitcase (GWT Compile Project).